# Appendices as sections in TOC using memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices, appendix

While using the memoir class, I would like to show my appendices as:
[image]
Like in the image, I want the individual appendices as sections under the common header "Appendices".

My simplified code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
    \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection}
    \makeatother
    \chapter{First Appendix}
    \chapter{Second Appendix}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following:

[image]

Are there any solutions for getting the appendix format indicated before?

Thank you

EDIT: Added simplified code, added my result, eliminated other code

Comment: Instead of `\input` or `\include`, can you provide a stand-alone minimal example that allows the community to replicate your behaviour? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @Werner Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at section **6.2.1 Appendices** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

Don't use the `appendix` package as `memoir` covers that code (just in a slightly different manner). The macro `\appendixpage` macro inserts an Appendices page in the document and adds the title to the ToC. So, something like the following (untested):

```
    \appendixpage
    \begin{appendices}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
    \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection}
    \makeatother
    \input{Appendices/A_Appendix}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
    \end{appendices}
```